# Using images saved in drawable in an app - Android

Tags: java, android, image, bitmap, drawable

I'm fairly new to android and was asked to improve an app. The app uses images which are saved in a file in the phone. I added a feature where the app also uses images that are saved in the drawable folder. However, the following code is not working now:

```
public static int[] getImageSize(Uri uri) {
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(uri.getPath(), options);
        return new int[] { options.outWidth, options.outHeight };
    }
```

Which returns the size of the image. I'm pretty sure it's not working because of the decodeFile() method. How can I fix this to make it work with my drawables too?

Comment: We wonder what you use in uri.getPath() now. But anyhow decodeFile() is not usable as there are no file system files in drwawables. You should use decodeFromStream instead. And open an Input streem from your resource in drawables. A little googling will give you the two lines of coe soon.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to check if the image is a bitmap from the file, or if it is a drawable first. Make a new function to get the drawable size with this code

```
public static int[] getImageSize(Drawable image) {
    int iHeight = image.getIntrinsicHeight(); 
    int iWidth = image.getIntrinsicWidth(); 
    return new int[] { iWidth , iHeight  };
}
```